# Class is freed instantly after it's put into unique_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, auto-ptr

I working currenly on server using Poco Net & Reactor Pattern.
I watned to do class CSConnection unique_ptr because class objects are referenced to worker thread pool.

Constructor :

```
    CSConnection::CSConnection(StreamSocket& socket, SocketReactor& reactor) : _socket(socket), _reactor(reactor)
    {
std::unique_ptr<CSConnection> autoptr(this);
        app.logger().information("Connection : " + _socket.peerAddress().toString());
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<CSConnection, ReadableNotification>(*this, &CSConnection::onReadable));
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<CSConnection, ShutdownNotification>(*this, &CSConnection::onShutdown));
        _reactor.addEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<CSConnection, ErrorNotification>(*this, &CSConnection::onError));
        _socket.setBlocking(false);
        sendSync();
    }
```

Destructor :

```
CSConnection::~CSConnection()
{
    app.logger().information("Disconnect : " + _socket.peerAddress().toString());
    _reactor.removeEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<CSConnection, ReadableNotification>(*this, &CSConnection::onReadable));
    _reactor.removeEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<CSConnection, ShutdownNotification>(*this, &CSConnection::onShutdown));
    _reactor.removeEventHandler(_socket, NObserver<CSConnection, ErrorNotification>(*this, &CSConnection::onError));
    if(player)
    {
        player->relase();
        if(player->hasActiveCharacter())
        {
            player->getActiveCharacter()->leaveGameWorld();
            player->nullActive();
        }
    }
}
```

And after that application free that class instantly (can be observed by "Disconnect" in server log).

What is there wrong ?
Thanks.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz he is not using an auto_ptr !

Comment: `unique_ptr` is not `auto_ptr`; similar but better. And at the end of the constructor your `autoptr` variable is destroyed and deletes `this`. Pretty sure that's not what you wanted.

Comment: have you considered using a function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::unique_ptr<CSConnection> autoptr(this);
```

After going out of the constructor it tries to delete `this` and calling the destructor. it's *undefined behavior* to use the deleted object after constructing it in this case.

Suicide (`delete this`) is rare and has special usage, for example in reference counted objects.

Comment: Ymm, but poco's socket acceptor create just plain pointer by new.

Comment: @user2971678 so manage *that* pointer with a smart pointer if you like - not `this` :)